# Rename Specific Worksheet Tabs

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to control which worksheet tabs get renamed.

```
Sub RenameSheets()
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleld = "Rename Worksheets"
    newName = Application.InputBox("Name",xTitleld,"",Type:=2)
    For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name <>"Signature" AND WS.Name <> "Invoice" AND WS.Name `<> "Cover" _ 
           Then Sheeets (i).Name = newName & i
    Next
End Sub
```

I want the worksheet tabs named AR1, AR2, etc. be changed.

I have many other sheets in the workbook. The code is changing all worksheet tabs.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `Option Explcit` in the first palce because you for sure have a typo here `sheeets(i).name`. Another question is: How did you set `ws`?

Comment: Tip: if something's not working as you expect, always remove On Error Resume Next. It will often then highlight exactly which line is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Select Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name`, it will simplify and shorten your code a lot. You can also add more names in the future.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub RenameSheets()

Dim i As Long
Dim newName As String, xTitleld As String

xTitleld = "Rename Worksheets"
newName = Application.InputBox("Name", xTitleld, "", Type:=2)

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Select Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        Case "Signature", "Invoice", "Cover"
            ' Do Nothing                
        Case Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = newName & i        
    End Select
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether the characters "AR" appear at the beginning of the name.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RenameSheets_AR()

    Dim I As Long
    Dim xTitleld As String
    Dim newName  As String

    ' Use only in specific circumstances
    'On Error Resume Next
    ' To increase debugging success see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

    xTitleld = "Rename Worksheets"

keyName:
    newName = Application.InputBox("Name", xTitleld, "", Type:=2)

    If newName = "" Then Exit Sub

    For I = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count
        If Left(Sheets(I).Name, 2) = "AR" Then
            Sheets(I).Name = newName & I
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```